# How to summarize rows and columns in R?

Tags: r, summarization, group-summaries

I have this kind of table:

```
           aaa     bbb   ccc 
  A         0       3     5    
  B         2       2     2    
  C         2       5     7
```

I get it using `anti_join` (for a table with non numeric values) and `table` command to group the result in a nicer way (something like countif in Excel).

```
da1 <- anti_join(data1,data2, by=c("pam1","pam2"))
table(da1$pam1,da1$pam2)
```

I was wondering if is possible to add also a Sum of each row and each column, so that in the result there will be something like this:

```
           aaa     bbb   ccc  SUM 
  A         0       3     5    8
  B         2       2     2    6
  C         2       5     7    14
 SUM        4      10     14
```

Comment: sure, it works, is there a way also to layout the result as in example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with `rowSums` and `colSums`

```
cbind(rbind(df, SUM = rowSums(df)), SUM = c(colSums(df), NA))

#     aaa bbb ccc SUM
#A     0   3   5   4
#B     2   2   2  10
#C     2   5   7  14
#SUM   8   6  14  NA
```

Comment: Layout is perfect, but if I try to apply it to a real table, the sum values are incorrect

Comment: @Ale Do you have any `NA` values in there. The above solution works on the sample data provided. You should add an example which represents your real data.

Comment: no, there is no NA, i mean it is very similar to an example above, but  it gives a Warning:   number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)

Answer (score 1):

An elegant option is `addmargins`

```
addmargins(as.matrix(df1))
#    aaa bbb ccc Sum
#A     0   3   5   8
#B     2   2   2   6
#C     2   5   7  14
#Sum   4  10  14  28
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(aaa = c(0L, 2L, 2L), bbb = c(3L, 2L, 5L), ccc = c(5L, 
2L, 7L)), .Names = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C"))
```